# How to translate Unicode to and from matlab?

Tags: excel, matlab, unicode

I have written matlab programs that produce plots and tables for chemical substances. I get my input mostly from excel tables and a local MySql database. My problem is quite a few substance names contain greek letters.

My problem is I want to create plots that use exactly the names specified by my collegues. And also create tables that show the correct symbol.

An example:
If I create an excel file containing: "α-Methylstyrol" in the first cell and read it with `[~,~,tmp] = xlsread('test.xlsx')`. tmp will contain `'(box with question mark)-Methylstyrol'`. If I use the string in a plot (`title(tmp)`) it will be shown as: `'(right arrow)-Methylstyrol'`

---

So far I tried the `native2unicode` and `unicode2native` commands on the string but there is no effect. Also I tried replacing the characters but the number of characters I need to replace is growing way too fast for me - so I'm really hoping there would be a more systematic way.

(We know there are also names that wouldn't contain greek letters - but we try to adhere to some guidelines which prefer these names.)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, Matlab does not support unicode nicely. However, it is possible to type greek letters in image titles using LaTex syntax.

```
title('\alpha-Methanol')
```

Even though it is not the nicest solution, I think it should be possible to replace unicode symbols with LaTex keywords.

Comment: As I wrote I considered this. It just seems way too much overhead just for having a feature I would consider "standard" nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

I think, your problem is, that `xlsread` is not even getting the correct greek letter out of your sheet.
Just give [jexcelapi](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) or [poi](http://poi.apache.org/) a try. Both links lead to java classes for importing xls-files. In MATLAB you only need to add the jar-file to you path via `javaaddpath` and the next steps are like basic java coding.

Comment: Actually the letter is correct: `double(tmp{1})` gives `945    45    77   101   116   104   121   108   115   116   121   114   111   108` - 945 seems the correct encoding: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3b1/index.htm

Comment: Hi @bdecaf - I tried with `MATLAB R2013a` and one `xlsx`-Sheet with just `α-alpha` in cell A1. `[a,b,c]=xlsread('C:\Users\ebelingb\Desktop\alpha.xlsx')` results in `a=[]`, `b=' -alpha'` and `c=' -alpha'`.   Have you tried the java class?